# Optimizing DB performance with multiple indices for one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I have timeseries data about a number of items that I store (in this toy example) in a simple pair of tables.  For now, this is done in MySQL, but if sufficiently strong reasons exist for trying to solve my problem in a different DBMS, I'd be all ears!

The `ITEM` table has a primary key and a single text-like column that can be thought of a description, let's call it `descr`.  The `DATAPOINT` table has a primary key and 3 other columns: a foreign key into the `ITEM` table (call it `fk_item`), a datetime i'll call `timestamp` and float value that we'll call `value`.  Further, there is a joint uniqueness constraint on the `(fk_item, timestamp)` column pair (we only want one value in the DB for a given item at a given time).

To put real numbers on it, the `DATAPOINT` table has about 1bn rows, which is the result of having approximately 100k rows for each of 10k distinct items.

My question is about the ability to optimize both read and write performance in this context, and the best way to enforce that uniqueness constraint.

A typical read from this DB will involve a small number of items (half a dozen?) for which we want to get all values in a given datetime range (containing approximately 1k points per item).  To that end, it would be very handy to have an index which is `(fk_item, timestamp)` and to enforce the joint uniqueness criteria on this index.  This motivation behind reads of this type is: "I want to make a line graph of 2 or 3 items for this 3 year range".

However, a typical write for this database would look very different.  It would be an insertion of a single data point for each of several thousand items, all with the same (or a small number of) timestamps.  This motivation for this kind of write can be thought of intuitively as: "I want to add yesterday's datapoint for every single item".  So for writes of that sort, it would be more practical to have an index which is `(timestamp, fk_item)`, and to enforce the uniqueness restriction on that index.

Importantly, for the scale of my data and hardware, neither of these indices can be fit entirely into RAM.

Typically, the vast majority of the writes happen in just a short time each day: i.e. at the end of each day all the data for that day gets written in a 15 minute period, and then reads occur throughout the day (but generally not during that 15 minute period).

So, from what I understand, if I build the table with the read-optimized `(fk_item, timestamp)` index (and put the uniqueness constraint there), then my typical reads will be nice and speedy.  But I'm concerned that my writes will be slow because we will need to update the index in a non-contiguous way.  However, if I build the table with the write-optimized `(timestamp, fk_item)` index (and put the uniqueness constraint there) then my typical writes will be speedy but my typical reads will suffer.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?  For example, if I build two indices: `(fk_item, timestamp)` *and* `(timestamp, fk_item)` and place the uniqueness *only* on the latter of the two, will that work well?  Or will writes still proceed at the "slow" speed because even though there is a write-optimized index (to check the uniqueness constraint, for example), the read-optimized index will need to be updated on any inserts, and that update will be non-contiguous?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont call the field `DESC`, that is a reserve word

Comment: I was hoping the answer would point me toward general principles applicable regardless of DBMS.  To the extent that the answer materially differs between, say `postgresql` and `sql-server`, it is totally plausible I'd pick the one that offers the best possible outcome to this question.  That said, I'll tag a couple possibilities in line with your question.

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza: Thanks, changed to `descr` in light of your comment.

Comment: I cant give you generic advice. But in postgresql I solve something like this creating [partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html) for day . That way insertions are very fast and reads only look for the days you need

Comment: Currently, I'm set up in mysql (and I've added that tag).  I truly appreciate your time to think this through in both the generic context, my current context, and, perhaps, the most ideal context.

Comment: I see. At first I thought this was a design question. But if you already have it running. Show us what queries are you using, the explain plan and the times you have, `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view). And looks like MySQL also support [partitions](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-mysql-partitions) but I have never use it

Comment: Do you have test data? Did you tried having both indexes? (Unique timestamp + fk, and non unique fk + timestamp) Is write and read performance acceptable in such a configuration? (PS if read query use unique index you can reorder columns in where clause to mach order of non-unique index thus forcing db to use it)

Comment: @przemo_li I don't think where clause order matters, but index hints can be used to force a specific index

Comment: I think of it as a design question in the sense that I have something running, but I want to know if I should have done it differently.  For the test data, I'm not sure a more efficient way to convey it.  Generate 10k random strings for `descr`.  That's your `ITEM` table.  Generate 100k random timestamps.  Take the full cross product of those with the items above to get 1bn `(descr, timestamp)` tuples.  For each, generate a random float.  That's the `DATAPOINT` table.  That's an accurate proxy for my situation.

Comment: As for the queries, a typical write would be: step 1) pick 5k out of 10k rows from the `ITEM` table.  step 2) generate 4 random timestamps.  step 3) Make up 20k floats to be your fake data to insert for those 20k new `DATAPOINT` rows.  That's all pre-work.  Now "start your timer" and try to insert it. For the read, it's like the situation in the original post: pick a half dozen items, pick a pair of timestamps that encompas about 1/10 of the data for those items.  "Start the timer" and do the select with a `WHERE` clause specifying those `descr`'s on the joined table and those date bounds.

Comment: This description is a bit too general. It would be helpful to see the real structure of tables, indexes and how the INSERT and SELECT queries that you want to optimize look like. I cannot imagine how a query for `pick 5k out of 10k rows from the ITEM table` would look like. The details really matter when you try to optimize database.

Comment: I appreciate your comment.  Here's the thing: I wan to know how a table like this *should be* constructed.  So while I can give you more details about how my system is currently arranged, I'm not married to my current system.  I want to hear how it *should be* arranged given the operational requirements mentioned above.  The phrase you highlighted is pseudocode for how you might (in another place, in python, say) generate fake data with which to populate a table if you wanted to try it on your end.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is a lot more specific than "the x table has ...".  "The typical read..." -- Show it to us!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  `(fk_item, timestamp)` only.

Long answer:

As far as *uniqueness* goes, `(fk_item, timestamp)` and `(timestamp, fk_item)` are the same.  While they both declare uniqueness equally well, they both suck at *being* unique.  Someday, a particular item will show up twice in the same second.

You did mention "yesterday".  So, if the entry is really a subtotal for the *day*, then `(fk_item, date)` is reasonable.

When building an index, it is alway better to have the date/time item *last*.  This is so that `WHERE fk_item = 123 AND date BETWEEN ... AND ...` can use that index.  Writes don't care (much) what order things are in.

What about the `PRIMARY KEY`?  It is, but MySQL's definition, `UNIQUE` and an `INDEX`.  So, if `(fk_item, date)` is reasonable, make it the PK.  This will make queries that need to look at several rows for a specific item more efficient.

"I want to make a line graph of 2 or 3 items for this 3 year range". -- If that involves millions of rows, then you have designed the schema inefficiently.  You need to build and maintain a Summary table of, say, daily values for each item.  Then it would be hundreds, not millions, of rows -- much more viable.

Back to the `INSERTs`.  With 10k distinct items and `PRIMARY KEY(fk_item, date)`, there would be 10K spots in the table where the insert occurs.  This is actually OK, and will be roughly the same speed as some other ordering.

The daily `INSERTs` are best done with either `LOAD DATA INFILE` or with multi-row `INSERTs`.

I am speaking from a MySQL perspective.  Some, though perhaps not all, of what I say applies to other products.

`PARTITIONing` is a useless idea for MySQL unless you intend to purge 'old' data.  (I can't speak for Posgres.)

If you insert rows *randomly* you may run into unrealistic performance problems.  This because your real situation will be much less "random".  There will be only 10K spots where you do `INSERTs` today, not 1 billion.  And tomorrow, it will be the 'same' 10K spots.

"how a table like this should be constructed" -- Minimize datatypes (eg, don't use an 8-byte `BIGINT` for a yes/no flag);  Provide the optimal PK (I suggested `(item, day)`).  But you *must* have tentative `SELECTs` in order to settle on the secondary indexes.  Normalize where appropriate (`item_id`), but don't over-normalize (dates).